# Binding an IIS website to a second ColdFusion instance

Tags: iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server, IIS7, Coldfusion 9.0.2. I created a 2nd CF instance, created an IIS website, used the web server configuration tool to bind the IIS website to the CF instance. Restarted IIS & CF windows services. It does not work as expected. It does not look like the IIS website is actually bound to the 2nd CF instance. With both the Windows IIS service and the new CF service running, I am able to hit the website and click around it.I then stop the CF service and the website still works. I would expect the website to not work when the CF Windows service was stopped. Any ideas as to what is going on?

Thanks ~Joe~

Here are the steps I did to create everything

- CF admin > instance manager > Add New Instance with create Windows service option
- create the website in IIS
- remove the windows CF service
- create a windows service and configure it to use a separate jvm.config file
- restart IIS & CF services
- use the web server configuration tool to bind the new CF instance to the new IIS website and checked off to configure web server for CF9 applications

Answer (score 3):

possible reasons are

1) web config tool created a new connector but it points to wrong instance.

2) your website is using the wrong connector

3) the website is inheriting the global connector instead

every time you use the web config tool to enable cf on a site it creates a new connector. this doesn't serve much purpose if you have once instance, so for reference you are better off to just add the handlers manually and use existing connector.
for multiple instance, you only need to use the web config tool ONCE to create the new connector, then just add handlers manually to any site you want to use that connector.
this way you only have as many connectors as you have instances, so it doesn't get confusing.

first we need to check which connector your site is using, so go into iis and check the cfm wildcard handler, and see what connector it points to, it should be different than your other site.

so your first site should for example be using the conenctor in 
C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\lib\wsconfig\1

and 2nd site using C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\lib\wsconfig\2

the numbers will differ according to how many times you have used web.config though.

in these connector folders open the file jrun_iis6_wildcard.ini

and look at the line 
bootstrap=127.0.0.1:51011

the proxy port should be different for multiple instances.
so on the connector for instance2, it should have a different port than the connector for instance1, if not, if you have any other connectors, then check the rest as well.
If they all have the same port, then they are all pointing to the same instance.
In which case, you simply need to change the port for the conenctor that SHOULD be pointing to instance2.
Generally CF just increments the port for each instance, so if it says 51011 then change it to 51012 and it should be working.

You should also make sure instance 2 is running by connecting to it using the built in web server, if you look in your cfadmin in the instance manager, it will have a link to open the cfadmin for each instance on the native port.

Comment: See Answer 1 for my resolution comments. Thanks snake!

Comment: I added, to snake's answer, a long text explanation of how I resolved it but it did not show up after review. Anyway, the issue was the wildcard handler was not pointing the the correct file. It needed to point to .....wsconfig/2/jrun_iis6_wildcard.dll - it was pointing to ...wsconfig/1/jrun_iis6_wildcard.dll which was being used by site 1.

Comment: no worries, glad my solution solved your issue, I have seen folks tearing their hair out for weeks with this.